# Chess negamax function

Tags: python, chess

Hi!

I'm trying to write a negamax search algorithm for my chess engine, but i can't seem to get it working. I'm using wikipedias pseudocode as an example, but somehow it doesn't produce the expected results. When i run it with a ply of 2, it changes my board data structure, although it shouldn't. After the function is finished running with ply 2, all of the white's (or black's. depends what player calls the function.) pawns are moved 2 spaces forward from starting position.

My make and unmake move functions are working perfectly , as i tested them with a non-recursive function that searches up to 5-ply. Then, it worked perfectly. There must be something wrong with my negamax implementation.

Thank you very much for your help!

```
def negaMax(self, board, rules, ply, player):
        """ Implements a minimax algorithm. """
        if ply == 0:
            return self.positionEvaluation()

        self.max_eval = float('-infinity')

        self.move_list = board.generateMoves(rules, player)
        for self.move in self.move_list:
            board.makeMove(self.move, player)
            self.eval = -self.negaMax(board, rules, ply - 1, board.getOtherPlayer(player))
            board.unmakeMove(self.move, player)

            if self.eval > self.max_eval:
                self.max_eval = self.eval

        return self.max_eval
```

Comment: You should really avoid using object variables (or static variables) when using recursive algorithms. I'd try to convert he algorithm to use only local variables, and try to debug it them. I can assure you that for the very least - it will be much easier to debug.

Comment: Yes. object variables are common for all recursive invokations. When one changes it - all see it. It results in much more complex code, which is a lot harder to follow, while a recursive code that only uses local variables is very self contained and much more understandable and easier to debug.

Comment: I really think it is the issue in here as well  (I suspect the board.unmakeMove(self.move,player) is not doing what you think it does because self.move was changed, but I could be wrong. I am 100% certain however - that avoiding as much as possible using object variables will make it a lot easier to find out what the problem is.

Comment: But how would you suggest i'd do that. The make and unmake methods are very closely related to the board class and i just can't take them out of there and put them into the eninge class. Maybe I'm not quite understanding what you mean , i'm just a beginner afterall :d . But thank you for your feedback.

Comment: There is no problem with the method being object method, the problem is with `self.move` - which was changed a lot of times, and is not your original move. Also `self.max_eval` is resetting it to `-infinity` at each recursive call - which is most likely not what you want.

Comment: I'm very sorry i think i'm not following you anymore. You are saying that i shouldn't use the variable named self.move ? And how does self.max_eval change the variable self.move? I'm never assigning self.move to max_eval. I'm very very sorry for my dumbness :d .

Comment: No need to be sorry. and you are not dumb. The problem (I think) is you are declaring `self.move`, instead of using it just as `move` - which will be a local variable, and not a class variable (at least in static languages, but I believe in python as well).

Comment: Let me wrap this discussion up as an answer/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue here is I believe the usage of object variables instead of local variable.

`self.move` is an *object variable*, every time you change it - every level of the recursion "sees" the change, which is usually a bad thing for recursive algorithms.

Recursive algorithms should be self contained, and do minimal if any change on the calling environment - it makes it much easier to walk over the flow of the algorithm.

The two main issues I see in this code are:

1. `self.move` should be a *local* variable (declare it as `move`). When you later do: `board.unmakeMove(self.move, player)` - I suspect that the board is undoing a different move, which was set deeper in the recursion tree, and not the one you intended. Using a local variable will eliminate this undesired behavior.
2. Each level of the recursive call is setting `self.max_eval = float('-infinity')` - so you constantly change it, though it is probably not what you want to do.

The solution should be something like that:

```
def negaMax(self, board, rules, ply, player):
        """ Implements a minimax algorithm. """
        if ply == 0:
            return self.positionEvaluation()

        max_eval = float('-infinity')

        move_list = board.generateMoves(rules, player)
        for move in move_list:
            board.makeMove(move, player)
            currentEval = -self.negaMax(board, rules, ply - 1, board.getOtherPlayer(player))
            board.unmakeMove(move, player)

            if currentEval > max_eval:
                max_eval = currentEval 
        return max_eval
```

I am not 100% certain it will indeed solve everything in the code (but it will solve some of it) but I am 100% certain avoiding object variables will make your code much easier to understand and debug.

Comment: Thank you for your comment - I renamed this variable. I am not much of a python expert, so I am unfamiliar with this issue.

Comment: <p>Thank you. It solved the issue that it changed the board data structure. I think the algorithm is wrong in some way , as with every ply, it produces the output 0. But i'm gonna try to figure this out tomorrow. </p>
<p> But, can you please explain when should i use object variables and when should i use local variables . I previously thought that when i decleare a variable inside a class, i have to put 'self.' in front of it :d . Again , thank you alot. </p>

Comment: You should use *object variables* when you want to change the *state* of the object. In every other scenario - you should use *local variables*